# Automatic API call using HTML textarea data

Tags: html, automation

I have an html form which includes a textarea box and a submit button that calls the API (say the Google Translate API, or Twitter API).

Now I wish to get rid of the submit button and automatically call the API once the user has entered input.
I also wish to have a limited number of API calls: ideally just one API call once the user has finished typing in that textarea.

What would be your recommendation on:

- the language to use (javascript, php, other)?
- the process: what triggers the API call?

Any pointer would be appreciated.

---

Edit -> About the "finished typing" part: I will never know if the user has finished typing. The only thing I might know is that there is no typing since x seconds. It would be great if I can detect inactivity since 1 or 2 seconds and trigger the API call. Is that possible and how?

Comment: Please clarify how you expect to detect "has finished typing". Good question contains 80% of the answer, yours will contain 99% after you change it.

Comment: @Eugene Mayevski 'EldoS Corp, Thanks for your feedback. I have edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PoltoS has given you information about keyUp and setTimeout. Also you can handle onBlur() event. Form is submitted using submit() method of the form. [See examples here](http://www.javascript-coder.com/javascript-form/javascript-form-submit.phtml). BTW you will probably find the sample for all parts of your question there.

Answer (score 1):

You can bind keydown/keyup events of your field to some function that runs `setTimeout` (with 5 seconds delay) after clearing old one. Once the function mentioned in setTimeout is called - the user has not typed for 5 seconds - execute your API call.

Better would be to show a countdown timer on the right to let user understand that something would happen in 5 or 10 seconds.

And of course it should be done using JavaScript - no additional request to server needed